# What is the Difference bw the Maximum CPU time on the Salesforce servers(10 second) and maximum execution time for each apex transaction (10 minute)

Tags: apex, governorlimits, cpulimit, transaction

What is the Difference between the Maximum CPU time on the Salesforce servers(10 second) and maximum execution time for each apex transaction (10 minute) ?

Comment: This question has been already answered here. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217079/45062

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete details about the apex transaction is given in the dev guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm?search_text=transaction).

> An Apex transaction represents a set of operations that are executed
> as a single unit. All DML operations in a transaction either complete
> successfully, or if an error occurs in one operation, the entire
> transaction is rolled back and no data is committed to the database.
> The boundary of a transaction can be a trigger, a class method, an
> anonymous block of code, a Visualforce page, or a custom Web service
> method.

CPU Time reference can be found in the dev guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).

> CPU time is calculated for all executions on the Salesforce
> application servers occurring in one Apex transaction. CPU time is
> calculated for the executing Apex code, and for any processes that are
> called from this code, such as package code and workflows. CPU time is
> private for a transaction and is isolated from other transactions.
> Operations that don’t consume application server CPU time aren’t
> counted toward CPU time. For example, the portion of execution time
> spent in the database for DML, SOQL, and SOSL isn’t counted, nor is
> waiting time for Apex callouts.

Consider a record update invoking an apex trigger execution. Now, this trigger execution will run in a single apex transaction and will time out if it doesn't complete execution within 10 minutes. However, within this transaction, there could be few SOQL & DML executions (*say 10 SOQL query and 2 DML *) or execution of validation rules, flows etc. The time spent in performing these SOQL & DML (*or rules, flows etc.*) will be **counted towards the transaction execution time**, but **not in the CPU usage time**. CPU usage time is calculated only based on the time spent while executing the current apex code (*or the apex code called by current code or anything within the control of developer (code) that uses application server CPU*). During DML execution there will be other actions performed like record-locking or waiting for lock to be released on records being processed or apex code compilation (*that cannot be controlled by the developer*). All this time will not be counted towards the CPU utilization time.

Check out this [old article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/09/script-limits-begone.html), if interested.

Comment: Please don't use images when you can copy text. This makes it inaccessible to those with vision problems (e.g. need a screen reader).

Comment: Good point @sfdcfox. Had not thought about this. Updated my answer with text.